# I want to toggle a mobile menu, i can add the class but it doesn´t remove it. javascript

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, navigation

I try to toggle the mobile menu, but I can't get it to close. It doesn't remove the class when clicking the **Close menu** button.

Adding works pretty fine. Is there something wrong with my if-statement? Thank you for helping me.

Full code is [on Github](https://github.com/raexune/Animation)

```js
const openMenu = document.querySelector('.open-menu');
const closeMenu = document.querySelector('.close-menu');
const navList = document.querySelector('.nav-list');
const navBurger = document.querySelector('.nav-burger');

// Toggle Menu
function toggleMenu() {
    if (navList.classList.contains('show-menu')) {
        navList.classList.remove('show-menu');
        closeMenu.style.display = 'none';
        openMenu.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        navList.classList.add('show-menu');
        closeMenu.style.display = 'block';
        openMenu.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

navBurger.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
```

```html
<nav>
    <h3 class="nav-logo"><img class="logo-icon" src="https://www.coditt.com/images/LogoPlaceholder.png" alt="placeholdeer" style="width: 75px"/> Vacation</h3>
    <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="nav-burger" href="#"><img class="open-menu" alt="open menu" />Open menu</a>

    <a href="#" class="nav-burger"><img class="close-menu" alt="close menu" />Close menu</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is hard to go through and not directly reproducible (you have a declared variable that is not defined). Ideal questions here have reproducible code that we can copy and paste to test. This is not that, please edit your answer and I'm sure you will get help more easily.

Comment: Thank you i will try my best. I am pretty new to this game.

Answer (score 0):

Use `navList.classList.toggle("show-menu")`.

So instead of:

```
function toggleMenu() {
    if (navList.classList.contains("show-menu")) {
        navList.classList.remove("show-menu");
        closeMenu.style.display = "none";
        openMenu.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        navList.classList.add("show-menu");
        closeMenu.style.display = "block";
        openMenu.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

It should be:

```
function toggleMenu() {
    navList.classList.toggle("show-menu");
}
```

EDIT:

As Raexune pointed out, my answer wasn't complete. So here is a better explanation..

```
<a class="nav-burger" id="open" href="#"><img class="open-menu" src="./img/menu-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="open menu"></a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-burger" id="close"><img class="close-menu" src="./img/close-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="close menu"></a>

function toggleMenu() {
    navList.classList.toggle('show-menu')
    openMenu.style.display = 'none';
    closeMenu.style.display = 'block';
}

function untoggleMenu(){
    navList.classList.toggle('show-menu');
    openMenu.style.display = 'block';
    closeMenu.style.display = 'none';
}



document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', untoggleMenu);
```

This isn't really the best answer, still.. but you can take some points. I used `id` instead of `class`, which should be better since `class` can return an `array` and so you have to indicate which instance you are manipulating. I believe that was the problem with the code not closing the menu.

And second, there is a better way to use the functions that I used but I left it there to make it understandable as to how I manipulated these instances separately.

Comment: thank you, i tried this and i think it works too. but with that the close button isn´t even showing anymore. i think the problem is in my css-file. i will have a look on that.

Comment: @raexune I edited to a better answer